# Method to increase density of $k$-points

Tags: computational-physics, crystals

I've been working on a simulation for some time and I have seem to hit a stone wall. Basically I want to plot the spectral function: $A(\boldsymbol{k},\omega) $. I set $\omega=0$ to look at the gapless excitations and I am working on an $N\times N$ square lattice. The clarity of the plot depends on the density of $k$-points.

I get the general features I am supposed to get, but I need a higher resolution, which means more $k$-points. We can increase $N$ so we get more $k$-vectors in our BZ zone, but at a certain $N$ the eigen value solver for Matlab times out since it can only handle so much.

I need a way of getting more $k$-points with a fixed $N$. Are there any algorithms to do this?

Comment: You might look into Monte Carlo methods. These things can sometime have better scaling.

Comment: Don't try to use matlab for a big computation. Write you code in tranditional way: c or fortan.

Comment: The nonlinear differential equation solver is what makes matlab appealing for my project. I need to find an order parameter first. I thought up a few tricks to increase the density of k-points but doing what I am doing in c or fortran would not help...